# Failed to load Json -file in mvc project

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, json

I have a trouble with my `phones.json` file.
I added Folder *phones* and *phones.json* into my project.

[image: phones.json]

I wrote *homeController.js*:

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module("phonecatApp", []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl',['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
    $http.get('../phones/phones.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.phones = data;
    });

     $scope.orderPror = 'age';
}]);
```

after running a project i have error:
[image: exception]

Why does it fail to load phones.json? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: try this ./phones/phones.json

Comment: Can you also show where did you place your homeController.js?

Comment: my homeController be in Controllers folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys for your answers, i done it, i just add to *Web.config* the next code:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </staticContent>
   .....
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Ha! That explains it. Glad you got it sorted and thanks for posting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code, so it must be the path.

Have you tried opening `http://localhost:6059/phones/phones.json` directly in your browser? By the error you're seeing, opening it directly in your browser should also result in a 404.

I would also suggest trying to reference the file from your site's root path:

```
$http.get('/phones/phones.json').success(function (data) {
```

If that doesn't work then I'd suggest looking at assets that are successfully loading (such as an image) and check the path for those and see if you're able to navigate to the `phones.json` file.